# JVM spec: grammar for generic signatures requires lookahead

Tags: jvm, .class-file

In the spec for generic signatures, [ClassSignature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-ClassSignature) has the form

```
ClassSignature:
  [TypeParameters] SuperclassSignature {SuperinterfaceSignature}
TypeParameters:
  < TypeParameter {TypeParameter} >
TypeParameter:
  Identifier ClassBound {InterfaceBound}
ClassBound:
  : [ReferenceTypeSignature]
InterfaceBound:
  : ReferenceTypeSignature
```

So the superclass bound of a type parameter can be omitted (some [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486081/java-bytecode-signatures)).

If I have a class declaration `public class A<T, LFooBar>`, the Java compiler generates the signature `<T:Ljava/lang/Object;LFooBar:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;`.

IUC, the class bound could be omitted, in which case the signature would be `<T:LFooBar:>Ljava/lang/Object;`.

Parsing that short signature requires looking ahead to the second `:` in order to know that `T:LFooBar:` are two type parameters, and not one type parameter `T` with class bound `FooBar`.

Maybe in practice, leaving away the class bound is only done if there's an interface bound? For `public class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, javac produces the signature `<T::Ljava/lang/Comparable<-TT;>;>Ljava/lang/Object;`. But I guess i cannot rely on this assumption.

Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, the only thing that can follow an omitted `ReferenceTypeSignature` is an `Identifier` or a `>`. Since `ReferenceTypeSignature` must either begin with an `[` or end with a `;` and identifiers can't contain these characters, while identifiers must be followed by a `:`, which can't appear type signatures, there is no ambiguity between those options.

Note that identifiers can start with `>`, so you need to look ahead for a colon to determine whether you are at the end `TypeParameters` or not. But that's a separate issue.

I'm not sure how the JVM implements it, but one possible approach is this:

- Examine the first character. If it is [, you have a type signature. If it is >, scan ahead for the first [, ;, or :. If the first one you see is :, that means you have identifier, otherwise you have end of type parameters.
- Otherwise, scan ahead for the first ; or :. If it is :, you have a identifier, otherwise you have a class bound.

Edit: Identifiers in signatures cannot contain `>`, so ignore that bit. (They also can't contain `:`, another potential source of ambiguity)

Comment: Thanks, so scanning ahead is what I'm doing, and it seems to be necessary. You mention "Note that identifiers can start with >" - can you provide a reference? The spec says "The grammar includes the terminal symbol Identifier [...] Such a name must not contain any of the ASCII characters . ; [ / < > :" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1)

Comment: The JVM doesn’t implement it at all, as the JVM doesn’t care for Generics. Within [the Reflection code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/reflect/generics/parser/SignatureParser.java#SignatureParser.parseBounds%28%29) there’s no look-ahead at all. So the assumption that “*leaving away the class bound is only done if there's an interface bound*” might be true, but it’s still a mismatch between the specification and the implementation and we don’t know, in which direction the fix will go.

Comment: @Lukas Sorry, it looks like I was wrong about that bit.