# Is it possible to decompile Java bytecode back to original generic type parameters

Tags: java, generics, bytecode, decompiler

I know Java compiler replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded during the process of Type Erasure. The produced machine bytecode would reflect the replaced bounds or `Object`.

Is there a way to take the resulted machine bytecode and decompile it back to a Java file that contains the original type parameters in generic types? Does there exist a decompiler that can achieve this? Or this process is simply irreversible due to the nature of compiling process?

Comment: Since types are erased, how do you suppose bytecode to be decompilable to generics?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802927/java-generics-is-any-meta-information-about-the-generic-type-preserved-at-runt

Comment: @AndyTurner The question is about restoring *original type parameters*.

Comment: Are you talking about restoring type variables in a type *definition*, or type arguments where a generic type has been *instantiated*?  For example, are you asking whether you could decompile `ArrayList.class` and get the source code for the generic type `ArrayList<T>`, including the declaration of `T`?  Or are you asking if, upon decompiling a method containing a variable `List<String> myList`, you would see the variable typed as `List<String>` in the decompiled method, as opposed to simply `List`?  These are two very different possibilities.

Comment: I am referring to the first scenario. Is there a way to decompile java machine bytecode such that I can see `<T>` in the reverted code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that, at the bytecode level, much information gets lost when you define and interact with generic types.  Type erasure was nice for preserving compatibility: if you mostly enforce type safety at compile time, you don't need to do much at runtime, so you can reduce generic types to their 'raw' equivalents.

And that's the key: compile time verification.  If you want the flexibility and type safety of generics, your compiler has to know a lot about the generic types you interact with.  In many cases, you won't have the source code for those classes, so it has to get the information from *somewhere*.  And it does: metadata.  Embedded in the `.class` file alongside the bytecode is wealth of information: everything the compiler needs to know you're using generic library types safely.  So what kind of generics information gets preserved?

**Type variables and constraints**

The most basic thing a compiler needs to know in order to consume a generic type is the list of type variables.  For any generic type or generic method, the names and positions of the type variables are preserved.  Moreover, any constraints (upper or lower bounds) get included as well.

**Generic supertype signatures**

Sometimes you write a class that extends a generic class or implements a generic interface.  If you write a `StringList` that extends `ArrayList<String>`, you inherit a lot of functionality.  If someone wants to use your `StringList` *as intended* and without the source code, it's not enough for the compiler to know that you extended `ArrayList`; it has to know you extended `ArrayList<String>`.  This applies transitively up the hierarchy:  it has to know `ArrayList<>` extends `AbstractList<>`, and so on.  So this information gets preserved.  Your class file a will include the complete generic signatures of any generic supertypes (classes or interfaces).

**Member signatures**

The compiler can't verify that you're using a generic type correctly if it doesn't know the full generic types of fields, method parameters and return types.  So, you guessed it: that information gets included.  If any part of a class member contains a generic type, wildcard, or type variable, that member will get its signature information saved in the metadata.

**Local variables**

It's not *necessary* to preserve information about local variable types in order to consume a type.  It can be useful for debugging, but that's about it.  There are metadata tables that can be used to record the names and types of variables, and the bytecode ranges at which they exist.  Depending on the compiler, they may or may not be written by default.  You can force `javac` to emit them by passing `-g:vars`, but I believe they're omitted by default

**Call sites**

One of the biggest issues for decompilers, mostly affecting generic inference within method bodies, is that call sites invoking generic methods retain *no information* about type arguments.  That creates huge headaches for APIs like Java 8 Streams, where generic operators get chained together, each one accepting anonymously typed lambdas (which may be contravariant in their argument types and covariant in their return types).  That's a type inference nightmare, but it's an issue for any code that happens to *interact with* generics.  That kind of code doesn't become substantially harder to decompile simply because it exists *within* a generic type.

**How this affects decompilation**

Modern Java decompilers like Procyon and CFR should be able to reconstruct generic types reasonably well.  If the local variable metadata is available, the results should be pretty close to the original code. If not, they'll have to try to infer generic type arguments in method bodies based on data flow analysis.  Essentially, the decompiler must look at what data flows in and out of generic instantiations, and use what it knows about the type of that data to guess the type arguments.  Sometimes it works really well; other times, not so much (see earlier comment about Java 8 Streams).

At the API level, though—type and member signatures—the results should be spot-on.

**Caveats**

Strictly speaking, all of the metadata described here is *optional*: it's only needed at compile time (or decompile time).  If someone has run their compiled classes through an obfuscator, optimizer, or some other utility, all of this information could get stripped out.  It won't make a difference at runtime.

**tldr; Conclusion**

Yes, it is certainly possible to decompile generic types and methods with their type parameters intact.  Assuming the required metadata is present, getting the type and member signatures right is the 'easy' part.  Correctly inferring the type arguments of generic instances and method invocations is the tricky bit, but that's a problem for *any* code that happens to interact with generics.

As mentioned, Procyon and CFR should both do a pretty decent job of restoring generic types and methods.

Comment: My pleasure.  Try using `javap -v` on a generic type sometime and look for Signature attributes to see what gets written out.  You can also use Procyon with `-r -v` to force verbose disassembly mode (bytecode output).  Procyon gives you color-coded output on an ANSI-compatible terminal, making things a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

That depends mostly on whether the code has been obfuscated. While it is true that generics use type erasure, compilers typically include source level information such as generic types as metadata in the classfile for various reasons - reflection, debugging, compilation against closed source libraries, etc.

So for a well behaved classfile, it should be possible to get the information back. Whether there are any off the shelf tools for this, I don't know. A lot of decompilers do try to recover generic types, but I don't know how reliable they are.

If the code has been obfuscated, then all the metadata will be stripped out, so there is no hope of recovering the original generic types.

Answer (score -2):

Yes ,this is called as decompilation process to convert machine code or we can say it as byte code to its original source code but till some extent ! 
There are some decompilers are do exist!
What you need is to get some help of decompilers and put little bit of your efforts in order to convert this byte code to its generic type as you said.
But it's not possible to do such reverse engineering process with high accuracy ratio as the modern compilers are designed in such a way that they go through several steps in order to convert that source code to its machine code so what you can get back after reversing is a just Non human readable form assembly code but  the same work can be done easily till some extent with the help of decompilers.
"The java decompiler project "  or JD project is the thing what I talk about 
http://jd.benow.ca
Hope it makes your concept clear!

Comment: OP seems to be perfectly aware what a decompiler is, they look for a possibility to decompile original parameter types in generics. So you do not address the core point of the question in your answer.

Comment: @lexicore thanks for clarifying and you are right. I am aware what a decompiler is.